# Forgot Yaaleh V'Yavo by Mincha on Erev Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, rosh-chodesh-new-month

*Rosh Chodesh* is on Friday only, and someone forgot to say *Ya'aleh V'Yavo* in the *Mincha Amida*. It is now already after nightfall, and he remembers that he omitted it. Must he repeat the *Ma'ariv Amidah* to make up for his invalid *Mincha* prayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן כא - דין מי שלא התפלל האיך ישלימנה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0020_L2) says that since at night you will not say  יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא (since it's no longer Rosh Chodesh) so there's no point in repeating the Amida.

This is true whether Ma'ariv is Shabbat or a weekday.

> **סעיף ז'**:
>   טָעָה בְּרֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ בְּמִנְחָה, וְלֹא אָמַר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, וּלְמָחָר אֵינוֹ רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ, אִם כֵּן אַף אִם יִתְפַּלֵּל עַרְבִית שְׁתַּיִם, לֹא יַרְוִיחַ כְּלוּם, שֶׁהֲרֵי אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לוֹמַר עוֹד יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, וּבְלֹא יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, הֲרֵי כְּבָר הִתְפַּלֵּל עַל כֵּן אֵינוֹ מִתְפַּלֵּל כְּלָל לְתַשְׁלוּמִין. ‏

However, this seems to contradict the Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קח - מי שלא התפלל לסבת טעות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0019_L2) who says that one should say the Amida of Ma'ariv twice - the second time בְּתוֹרַת נְדָבָה. (In a nutshell: as a voluntary prayer).

> **יא**: טָעָה בְּמִנְחָה שֶׁל שַׁבָּת וְהִתְפַּלֵּל י''ח וְלֹא הִזְכִּיר שֶׁל שַׁבָּת, מִתְפַּלֵּל בְּמוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת  שְׁתַּיִם, וְאֵינוֹ מַבְדִּיל בַּשְּׁנִיָּה, וְיִתְפַּלֵּל אוֹתָהּ בְּתוֹרַת נְדָבָה וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְחַדֵּשׁ בָּהּ דָּבָר; וְהוּא הַדִּין אִם לֹא הִזְכִּיר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא בְּמִנְחָה שֶׁל  רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ.‏

However, the Mishna Brura ([ibid 36](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.106?lang=he)) points out that since on Shabbat one may not pray a בְּתוֹרַת נְדָבָה, then one cannot repeat the Amida on Shabbat to make up for the omission.

> **לו**: **של ר"ח** - אם חל ר"ח בע"ש והיה ר"ח רק יום אחד ושכח במנחה להזכיר של ר"ח ונזכר אחר שחשכה **אין להשלים כלל בליל שבת כיון דאינו מועיל כלום** ורק שיכול להתפלל בנדבה ואין מתפללין תפלת נדבה בשבת. ‏

**Conclusion:**  to answer your question.

If Rosh Chodesh is on Thursday-Friday or Friday only, and someone forgot to say Ya'aleh V'Yavo in the Mincha Amida and he remembers that he omitted it only after nightfall, he does **not** repeat the Ma'ariv Amidah to make up for his invalid Mincha prayer.

Comment: The Shulchan Arukh is saying to intend it as a Nedava because there's a Machloket if you really need Tashlumin. But when it's Shabbat, you can't intend that worst case it's a Nedava, so you are stuck. Tashlumin itself is not a Nedava and can be done on Shabbat. (If Fri night were also Rosh Chodesh, then for sure you are obligated in Tashlumin.)